# Resize actionbar background image

Tags: android, image, background, android-actionbar

I am using an image for my actionbar background. It works great on most devices, but is a bit wide for small screens. Is there a simple way to resize the background image in the actionbar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about creating a media query for mobile devices?

I'm not sure if you're using media queries, but within your .css file, you would (usually at the bottom of the file) create a media query (where your .css file searches for devices with a particular size) and then changes elements of your page (namely, your image size or location) once it detects a mobile or smaller device.

```
@media handheld {
    .actionbar {
        background-image: background_small.jpg;
        background-position: top center;
    }
}
```

The important point to take away from here is that the practice of making sure the images you are using for your mobile devices are smaller **or** are positioned differently than the tablet and desktop devices.

On top of this **media query**, you may want to ensure, you're already checking that the person's mobile device is using the dimensions you would like it to use (for instance, the mobile device is not showing your website in full desktop layout). For that, make sure you add this line towards the bottom of your header tag (on your main template page, if you're using templates):

```
<head>
    .... (other code, like stylesheets or jquery/javascript links)
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is native Android, suppose I should include that in the question.

Comment: @user2471908, oh apologies!